# How do i add doneaction and change the done text?

Tags: swift, xcode, iqkeyboardmanager

I am using IQKeyboardManager and i added custom action for the done button

```
txtfield.addDoneOnKeyboard(withTarget: self, action: #selector(doneButtonClicked), titleText: "Next")

IQKeyboardManager.shared().toolbarDoneBarButtonItemText = "Next"

@objc func doneButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    //  do stuff
}
```

Here the action gets called and everything works. But the title of the donebutton is DONE (in bluecolor).

The "Next" is show at the middle of the keyboard as titletext. How do i change the text/color of the done button? If i dont add any action to any specific textfield, the second line works perfectly , but anytime i add action, the custom name for done button is ignored.

Any help?

[IQKeyboardManager in github](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
 let config = IQBarButtonItemConfiguration(title: "Next", action: #selector(doneButtonClicked))
txtfield.addKeyboardToolbar(withTarget: self, titleText: nil , rightBarButtonConfiguration: config, previousBarButtonConfiguration: nil, nextBarButtonConfiguration: nil)

//  any color you like
txtfield.keyboardToolbar.doneBarButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red], for: UIControl.State.normal)
```

Instead of:

```
txtfield.addDoneOnKeyboard(withTarget: self, action: #selector(doneButtonClicked), titleText: "Next")
```

---

what is more? `titleText` sets `toolbar.titleBarButton.title`.

I pick some code snip from `IQKeyboardManager` source code here:

```
      //Title button
     toolbar.titleBarButton.title = titleText
```

while `toolbarDoneBarButtonItemText` set's `doneBarButton.title`

some code snip from `IQKeyboardManager` here:

```
    if let rightConfig = rightBarButtonConfiguration {

        var done = toolbar.doneBarButton

        if rightConfig.barButtonSystemItem == nil && done.isSystemItem == false {
             done.title = rightConfig.title
             done.image = rightConfig.image
             done.target = target
             done.action = rightConfig.action
        }
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.

txtfield.keyboardToolbar.doneBarButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red], for: UIControl.State.normal)

Only needed this part . Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

1. import IQKeyboardManagerSwift
2. IQKeyboardManager.shared.toolbarDoneBarButtonItemText = "NEXT"

See below picture has the NEXT button in Xcode 10.1.

[image]

Comment: This wont work. This only works when no custom action is added to done button. If i tried adding custom action, the done button defaults to DONE (in blue colour) , if there is no custom action, this works.